# Como funciona o Grid System no Angular Material Design?

Tags: angular, grid, material-design, angular-material

Na [documentação](http://material.angular.io) do Angular Material Design possui um componente chamado Grid List, que, imagino eu, seja a parte de estruturação do layout, porém ele só tem dois exemplo muito simples e não consegui entender seu uso, então...

1. Estou certo, o Grid List é isso mesmo?
2. Se não qual seria o componente pra isso ou devo fazer na mão?
3. Como usar?
4. No Material Design Lite costumava usar as classes, por exemplo, `mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--1-offset` em um container para que os elementos não fiquem grudados na borda, como fazer o mesmo no angular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o [Material Grid List](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples), para fazer um layout de colunas de forma responsiva em conjunto com o [Angular Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout), mas você vai precisar de um pouco de código.

**TL;DR;** Va para o [link](https://brianflove.com/2017/05/03/responsive-angular/) de referência, em inglês, mais detalhado que o exemplo abaixo.

O Angular Flex Layout utiliza ***breakpoints*** para detectar o tamanho da tela:

- **xs** - max-width: 599px;
- **gt-xs** - min-width: 600px;
- **sm** - min-width: 600px; max-width: 959px;
- **gt-sm** - min-width: 960px;
- **md** - min-width: 960px; max-width: 1279px;
- **gt-md** - min-width: 1280;
- **lg** - min-width: 1280px; max-width: 1919px;
- **gt-lg** - min-width: 1920px;
- **xl** - min-width: 1920px; max-width: 5000px;

Você pode usa-los para definir um layout, `fxLayout`, em linhas(`row`) ou colunas(`column`), ou mesmo visibilidade de objetos com `fxShow` e `fxHide`, como abaixo:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutAlign.xs="center stretch" class="row-example">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div fxShow="true" fxHide.xs="true"></div>
</div>
```

No codigo angular de seu componente, para detectar os *breakpoints*, você precisa de um serviço chamado `ObservableMedia`, que é instalado com o pacote Angular Flex Layout, abaixo os passos seguido de um exemplo:

```
$ npm install @angular/flex-layout --save
```

Você precisa importar o modulo no seu `app.module`:

```
...
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

Então nos componentes que desejar utilizar o layout responsivo, você precisa injetar o serviço `ObservableMedia`. No exemplo abaixo, usando o `mat-grid-list`, podemos usar o `ObservableMedia` para definir quantas colunas são exibidas por linha:

**HTML**

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="cols | async" gutterSize="16px">
  <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>5</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

**TS**

```
public cols: Observable<number>;

  constructor(private observableMedia: ObservableMedia) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const grid = new Map([
      ["xs", 1],
      ["sm", 2],
      ["md", 2],
      ["lg", 3],
      ["xl", 3]
    ]);
    let start: number;
    grid.forEach((cols, mqAlias) => {
      if (this.observableMedia.isActive(mqAlias)) {
        start = cols;
      }
    });
    this.cols = this.observableMedia.asObservable()
      .map(change => grid.get(change.mqAlias))
      .startWith(start);
  }
```

No código acima no `map` `grid`, são definidos os *Media Query Alias*, maAlias, que mapeiam os *breakpoints* dos tamanhos de tela, e associa os mesmos ao numero de colunas desejados.

Em `ngOnInit`, inicialização do componente, detectamos qual *breakpoint* está ativo para definir o numero de colunas inicial.

Por fim, inicializamos um `Observable` para monitorar mudanças de tamanho de tela ativados pelo serviço `ObservableMedia`, a cadas alteração, ajustamos o tamanho das colunas.

Fonte: https://brianflove.com/2017/05/03/responsive-angular/

Answer (score 1):

A lista de recursos do Projeto Material Angular não possui nenhum Sistema de Grid, seja ele por colunas, flexbox ou algum outro método. Este `component` Grid List nada mais é que um recurso para facilitar a implementação de um mosaico de imagens por exemplo, mas não serve como estrutura de grids para um layout em sí.

Como solução, recomendo que instale em seu projeto o [Angular Flex Box](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) que fornece uma API de Layout Grids sofisticada utilizando o Flexbox CSS e MediaQuerys.

Comment: Poderia adicionar exemplos de uso da biblioteca?